# Google fonts weight not properly displayed

Tags: css, webfonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

If I run the code below, the Josefine Sans font weight 400 looks bolder than weight 600. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <p style="font-weight:400;">The spectacle before us was indeed sublime.</p>
 <p style="font-weight:600;">The spectacle before us was indeed sublime.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please tell us in which browser.

Comment: Looks fine here in Chrome and FF on Win10. Maybe post an image of what you see.

Comment: Also looks fine to me in Chrome.

Comment: Resolved. It was a computer specific issue. There was a conflicting local font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my browser the 400 is lighter than the 600, so this might be computer specific.

The most likely reason is that you have installed a faulty or incomplete version of the webfont locally/on your computer.

Comment: Thank you!!!. You're absolutely right. The same font was installed locally and I deactivated it, then the webfont look fine now.